# How can access the headers of an incoming request in tritium?

Tags: ajax, http-headers, moovweb

I would like to be able to add some logic to my tritium project based on the incoming request header. Is it possible to access the header information and then perform match() with() logic?

My plan is to take an existing URL (that can be accessed via a normal GET request) and give it a second mode of functionality so that it can be turned into an AJAX API. When the JavaScript makes the API request, I could set a custom header flag so that the platform knows to interpret the request differently.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to access headers in the incoming HTTP request using the global variable syntax. For example, to access the site's hostname:

```
$host
# => yourwebsite.com
```

I believe that most of the standard headers are accessible as global variables in Tritium. However, I'm not sure if **all** headers are accessible as global vars.

Inside your project folder, on your development machine, there should be a `tmp` folder that contains the HTTP request/response bundles. Each bundle should be time stamped with the request's date and time. I think if you peek inside one of these folders, you should see a bunch of files:

- incoming_request
- incoming_response
- outgoing_request
- outgoing_response

And possibly a fifth file. I can't remember if this is still the case in the current version of the platform, but there's a chance you'll find a fifth file containing the global variables that the Tritium server creates to store HTTP request header values. So you can peek inside that file (if it exists) and find out what variable name your HTTP headers are using.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I believe there are two, initial-env.json and final-env.json.  You can find all the global variables that are set for you at the start of tritium execution in initial-env.json, including the request headers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm late on this one, but I figured I would lend a hand to anyone else who needs help on this one.

you need to create two files in your scripts directory, one called

request_main.ts

and

response_main.ts

You can then use things such as the parse_headers function, which iterates through the request/ response headers, depending on the file which you put the code in.

```
parse_headers() {  # iterate over all the incoming/outgoing headers
  log(name())      # log the name of the current cookie in the iteration
  log(value())     # log the value of the current cookie in the iteration
}

parse_headers(/Set-Cookie/) {  # iterate over the Set-Cookie headers only.
  log(this())
}
```

This will log all of your header names, to make modifications, you can then use "setter" functions, which you can read about here:

http://developer.moovweb.com/docs/local/configuration/headers

Good luck.